# How to know if 3D Secure for Stripe is succeed or failed?

Tags: android, validation, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I'm new to Stripe.

I've checked out the Stripe sample app and I've been able to redirect user to stripe web to validate 3D Secure with the url got from `Source` object:

```
String url = source.getRedirect().getUrl()
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

However, then intent returned from the web has no info for the result if it succeed or failed. The data contains only `client_secret`, `livemode` and `source` key.

How do I know if the 3DS process succeeded or not?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for the `source.chargeable` webhook event on your server, which lets you know that the authentication was successful and you can now charge the 3DS source. https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure#webhooks

Comment: Thank you, looks like it cannot be done on android side

Comment: hai, i am facing the same issue. can i check the webhook event status in my client side?

Comment: One more issue, in test mode after the verification the stripe web page still exit below my activity, why it closes automaticaly?